# What is the equivalent DB create command for Sequel ORM?

Tags: ruby, sequel

What is the AR equivalent of `bundle exec rake db:create`?

I tried

```
sequel -m path/to/migration postgres://uname:password@host/dbName
```

which is the only command I could find in the documentation (so far). Obviously I am looking for something to create a DB not migrate, which works fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sequel doesn't have commands to create databases.  The way `rake db:create` works is by calling the programs that ship with the databases (assuming that the commands are in `$PATH`).  The Sequel equivalent for `rake db:create` with PostgreSQL would be running `createdb` manually.

Comment: exactly what I landed up doing. The curtain has been officially pulled! Thank you for your hard work!